# Saving presto query output to a file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL, but I have to query some results using `psql` in an interactive command line session. I am connecting through a cluster and I would like to extract the output of the query into a file for further analysis.

The command I use to connect is `psql -h hostname.with.dbs -p 5432 -U my-username` and inside I do the query. But it is not clear to me how to pipe that into a file in my user folder in the machine used to connect to Presto.

If I have to add more details, let me know, as I am not an expert and might forgot to add important information. Thank you all!

Comment: `psql` is a client tool for PostgreSQL, not PrestoSQL. Can you confirm which one you're actually using?

Comment: You were right! Sorry for the confusion. I edited it already.

Comment: You can use `\copy` to store the result of a query into a local (text) file. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY

Comment: I used ```\g filename``` as answered below. Do you know what difference they have, if any? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to that. Basically appending `\g file_name;` at the end of the query. It saves the file in the directory where I launched the command to connect to the database. I didn't try to add full path to the file name, but I assume it would work as well.